# Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)) on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject.Copy

Tags: .net, excel, com-interop

i am working with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, to copy excel chart into power point using Asp.net.
It works fine in visual stdio IDE but as i  I deploy it on server.
 it gives an error ,
Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))

this erorr generted by code when it copies the charobject ,Only data copies perfectly fine.

problem is with chartobject.copy() function.
I googled alot but it gives nothing
 please help me.

Moazzam

Answer (score 0):

Office interop is NOT supported by MS in server-side scenarios (like ASP.NET or Windows Service) - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

For server-side handling of Excel files you will need to use some 3rd-party library - there are several free and commercial libraries available:

- [MS provides the OpenXML SDK V 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx) (free)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (free)
- [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free)
- [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free)
- [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial)
- [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) (commercial)
- [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) (commercial)
- [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) (commercial)