# Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)) on ChartObject.CopyPicture

Tags: excel, windows-services, interop, excel-charts

I am working with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (Excel 2010 64 BIT), to copy excel chart into power point using  Windows Service deployed on Windows Server 2012 64 BIT. It works fine in a Local machine with same configuration but as I deploy it on production server. It gives an error, Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)) 
This error generated by code when it copies the chart object, If I copying data working fine.
Problem is with chartobject.CopyPicture function. I googled alot but it gives nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344598/unspecified-error-exception-from-hresult-0x80004005-e-fail-on-microsoft-off